# Oracle SQL - Materialized view - fast refresh with package call is giving "complex query" error

Tags: sql, oracle, view, materialized-views, fast-refresh

I have a materialized view and I need to add specific functionality to one of the columns that is included in the MView. The functionality is to call a specific package if the value of column is Y, else just take as is. I know that we cannot use DECODE for fast refresh, so I tried to use UNION ALL and split it into 2 queries.

```
create materialized view test_mview 
(
col1,
col2,
..
)
build immediate
fast refresh 
with primary key as
select p_tes_pkg(ta.col1), ta.col2,.. 
from table_a ta, table_b tb, table_c tc 
where ta.id = tb.ta_id 
  and tb.code = tc.tb_code 
  and ta.col1 = 'Y' 
  and tb.type in ('ABC','DEF')
  and tb.type_id is not null
  and ta.code = tc.ta_code
  and regexp_like (ta.name, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
union all 
select ta_2.col1, ta_2.col2,.. 
from table_a ta_2, table_b tb_2, table_c tc_2 
where ta_2.id = tb_2.ta_id 
  and NVL(ta_2.col1,'N') = 'N'
  and tb_2.code = tc_2.tb_code
  and tb_2.type in ('ABC','DEF')
  and tb_2.type_id is not null
  and ta_2.code = tc.ta_code
  and regexp_like (ta_2.name, '^[[:digit:]]+$')
;
```

This is still giving the same error. So, I tried to create a view with the select query and use it to create the MView. Still same error. Please help and thanks in advance.

Error:

```
ORA-12015: cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query
12015. 00000 -  "cannot create a fast refresh materialized view from a complex query"
*Cause:    Neither ROWIDs and nor primary key constraints are supported for
           complex queries.
*Action:   Reissue the command with the REFRESH FORCE or REFRESH COMPLETE
           option or create a simple materialized view.
```

Comment: you must provide the structure behind of tables and package. Use `case` instead of `decode`

Comment: You can use dbms_view.explain_mview to see why it is raising the error.

Comment: @RobertoHernandez, I tried case instead of decode. But without the package call, it is creating the MView, but with it I am getting this error.